# How can I transform this url with REGEX?

Tags: c#, regex, url-rewriting, dotnetnuke

I have a dynamic web app built using DotNetNuke that uses the following url format:

```
/SeoDummy.aspx?template={VAR1}&keywords={VAR2}
```

My user friendly url format is like this:

```
http://domain.com/.{VAR1}/{VAR2}
```

I am really terrible with REGEX and need to somehow detect when the user friendly url is requested and rewrite it with the dynamic web app url.  I have tried the following, but It is not catching it on the site, it is just 404'ing:

```
.*/^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$
```

I am sure you that know regex will find my attempt silly, but regex is my kryptonite!

Thanks for any help that can be offered.

Comment: Is this for any query string parameters or strictly with parameters `template` and `keywords` ?

Comment: just those 2 parameters are needed

Comment: the main issue for me needing this, is I have been using a config file with all my rewrites but the site is growing fast and they have about 55,000 url's that follow this pattern and the site's memory usage is spiking and the performance is slipping badly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using some custom url,I guess regex would be better than using [URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class

---

In your regex you have misplaced `^`..The regex should be

```
^https?://domain[.]com/[.]([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$
```

Comment: +1. And the Rewrite would be: `/SeoDummy.aspx?template={R:1}&keywords={R:2}`

Comment: this one works, but how can I make it so it will only match if the dot is there?

Comment: OK, I got that..: */\.([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$

Comment: @box86rowh where do you want to match `.`

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this, but give it a shot and tell me how it works out:

```
domain[.]com/\.([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$
```

It looks like you had it mostly right except for the first carat, marking the beginning of the string... which is impossible since you specified `.*` right in front of it! Also you missed the period in front of `{VAR1}` (unless that is a typo?).

I also wouldn't put `.*` at the beginning because then you could be capturing `VAR1 = domain.com`, `VAR2 = something that is actually VAR1`

If you want to become immune to your kryptonite, then this website is really good for looking up stuff:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html